# Is List.addAll() is the most efficient way of appending a large list for Android?

Tags: android

```
List<Byte> listData, listDataNew
...

listData.addAll(listDataNew);
```

`listData.addAll(listDataNew)` takes about 100 milliseconds when listDataNew's size is about 1.5 million on an Android 9 device and almost 1 second on an old Android 6 device.

I have seen recommendations for using addAll for appending large lists. Is it the most efficient method?

Comment: @blackapps I edited the post to make it clearer in light of your question : "listData.addAll(listDataNew) takes about 100 milliseconds when listDataNew's size is about 1.5 million on an Android 9 device and almost 1 second on an old Android 6 device."

Comment: Hmm, I cannot find "2.5 million". Where did you see it?

Comment: The size of List<Byte> listDataNew is 1.5M.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256165/discussion-between-hong-and-blackapps).

Comment: It should be the fastest way, but in general List<Byte> is quite inefficient. If you can, I'd suggest to use a byte array or a ByteBuffer instead

Comment: @SergeiKozelko Thank you. Could you turn your comment into an answer for me to accept?